# How do I Delete Old Audio Drivers

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers

I have installed many inf-modified audio drivers for Conexant 20585 to make the **stereo mix** appear. (Failed though..)

And now there are so many installed audio drivers in the system driver store.

So, **How do I delete the modified/unsigned drivers from my computer?**
[image]

**Summary of the following discuss**

1. I want to delete the unused/modified/unsigned drivers, just keep the
   one in use and the signed ones.
2. I expect an easy automatic way to find the unsigned drivers listed in
   the figure.
3. I don't want to read the thousand-lines inf file to manually remove
   the driver files.

Comment: Go to Device Manager and uninstall them.

Comment: @Tom That won't work. I also use **devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices** to show hidden installed devices. The problem here is all the drivers installed **have the same hardware ID**, so only one entry will be listed in device management.

Comment: Go find them in `C:\Windows\inf`.  Read the inf to find associated files.  Delete files and inf.

Comment: The best way.  If the driver is being used.  Remove the device and select the option to delete the driver when you do.  Its not clear "why" this isn't an option.

Comment: @techie007 This doesn't meet my requirements. 1)Only INF is deleted but the rest of driver files are still there. 2)The inf file name is renamed from the original one. New names is like oemXX.inf, and it's not easy to find all of them.

Comment: @lesca - Why do you want to delete unused INF files exactly?  What makes you think you need to update the driver?

Comment: @Ramhound Uninstall the driver with "Delete the driver software for this device" checked will only delete the current driver inf and other files. The rest of the unsigned files are still there.

Comment: @lesca - Sure they exist on the system but they are used.

Comment: "Read the inf to find associated files. Delete files and inf." doesn't cover finding and removing the files you speak of?

Comment: @Ramhound I actually want to delete the unused/modified/unsigned drivers, just keep the one in use.

Comment: @techie007 Sure it does. But I have to manually check most of recent inf files and read the thousand-lines inf files... It's not efficient.

Comment: @lesca - Honestly.  The only way you will be able to find the inf files is if you look in the contents of all the files.  Windows search will do that.

Comment: @techie007 Seems only this way will work. I'd like to take your answer. You can post it below. One more question, how do I tell which inf is the one in use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pnputil -e` to enumerate all installed drivers and look for the OEM infs which belong to the drivers you want to remove. Now use `pnputil -d OEMNumber.inf` to delete the drivers.

If you want a GUI, use [this tool to remove them](http://driverstoreexplorer.codeplex.com/):

[image: screenshot of Driver Store Explorer]

Run it, select "Enumerate" to get all drivers, select which ones you want to be killed and click on "Delete package".